# Accessing the response headers when using $resource service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an web api POST method that returns a location header in the http response message when I post a message object that is saved successfully. The Post method is as follows:

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Message message)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // code to save message in database 
                    ... 

                    result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

                    result.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, "messages/" + message.Id.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, GetErrorMessages());
                }

            return result;
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetErrorMessages()
        {
            return ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
```

In my angular service, I am using the $resource service to make the POST request as follows:

```
myApp.factory("messageRepository", ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return {       
        save: function(message) {
            return $resource('/api/messages').save(message);
        }
    };

}]);
```

In my angular controller, I am calling the save method of my angular service and use the $promise.then() to check for success and error:

```
myApp.controller('MessageController', ['$scope', 'messageRepository', '$location', '$timeout',
    function ($scope, messageRepository, $location, $timeout) {

    $scope.errors = [];

    $scope.save = function (message) {

            $scope.sendingdata = true;

            accountRepository.save(message).$promise.then(
                // handle success
                function (data) {


                },
                // handle error
                function (response) {
                       $scope.errors = response.data;   
                });
        };

    }])
```

How do I access the response location header in the success handler function in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a success function to the save method that will have the headers as an argument. Try this:

```
myApp.factory("messageRepository", ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return {       
        save: function(message) {
            return $resource('/api/messages').save(message, function(value, responseHeaders) {
                       return responseHeaders().Location;
            });
        }
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks Fordio. responseHeaders().location returns the location. How do I access this value from the controller??